# Código Vue não é identatado no VS Code

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Fala galera!

Baixei o Visual Code recentemente e trabalho muito com arquivos do tipo vue (Uma framework de javascript), no entanto nenhuma das extensões que baixei do VS Code identa o código, simplesmente não acontece em nada e está bem difícil trabalhar sem conseguir ter o código linear. Alguém ai sabe o que eu posso fazer ?

Comment: Ué mas, como assim, só em arquivos .vue?

Comment: Arquivos com a extensão .vue não são identados, esse é o problema

Answer (score 1):

Opa Matheus, tudo certo?

Para formatar os códigos normalmente selecionamos na parte inferior direita do VsCode (Na imagem está Javascript ao lado de ESLint) o tipo de linguagem que estamos trabalhando e dependendo das configurações vc pode salvar e o VsCode se encarrega de salvar já formatado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou se não poderá selecionar alguma extensão como por exemplo o
 [vue-beautify](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=peakchen90.vue-beautify)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado, abraços!

Comment: Caso tenha te ajudado, por favor marque como resposta.

Comment: Infelizmente não funcionou